# Removing Space Before and After List of Equations in Latex

Tags: latex

I have created a list of equations which list all the equations perfectly. However there is a very big space before the title list of equations and after. I had same problem with table of contents, table of figures and table of contents but I solved them by these commands:

```
\setlength\cftbeforetoctitleskip{-5pt}
\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{15pt}

\setlength\cftbeforeloftitleskip{-5pt}
\setlength\cftafterloftitleskip{15pt}

\setlength\cftbeforelottitleskip{-5pt}
\setlength\cftafterlottitleskip{15pt}
```

So I am not sure if there is a similar solution as above. I searched a lot of different solutions in the internet with no luck. So any suggestion or hint will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow! Could you share a Minimal (not-)Working Example (especially with the preamble)?

Comment: The code of list equations is taken from one of the posts in stackoverflow and the link of it is in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173102/table-of-equations-like-list-of-figures. However I want to remove the space before and after the list of equation. The marked answer is the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have any space after the **list-of-myequations** (but the *title* of **list-of-myequations**) :-/

To reduce/increase the space before and after the title of **list-of-myequations** use

```
\setlength{\cftbeforeequtitleskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftafterequtitleskip}{0pt}
```

---

According to the documentation of [tocloft](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tocloft/tocloft.pdf), section 3.2 (cca. page 41 (at now)), you can create your own list with (e.g. as you linked):

```
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listofequationsname}
```

A few features you can change is listed there. The trick is to replace 'X' with 'myequations' and 'Z' with 'equ'. E.g.

```
\setlength{\cftbeforeXskip}{*length*} -> \setlength{\cftbeforemyequationsskip}{*length*}
\setlength{\cftbeforeZtitleskip}{*length*} -> \setlength{\cftbeforeequtitlesskip}{*length*}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working perfectly right now.